# this.filterManager.isExternalFilterPresent is not a function

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a project on react and I just updated package `@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model` to the latest version `^28.0.2`. Now all my ag grid tables through this error, but I am not using isExternalFilterPresent prop at all. How can i fix this issue, please help. Error image for reference here https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOGam.png

Comment: What are the node and react versions you're using ?

Comment: @KavinduVindika I am using node v18.0.0 and react ^18.1.0

Comment: Do you have any ag-grid packages on older versions? I'd suggest upgrading them all in parallel.

Comment: @AndrewGlazier ahh that works! fool mistake... I had some packages with version ^27.2.1 so that caused this error. Thanks for help!